# how to avoid printing None list in the output of python program

Tags: python, list

I started Learning python recently, I am trying to print all possible permutations of size k of the string S in lexicographic sorted order.

I am getting correct results but in the output, my program is also printing a None type list i.e : [None, None]

```
from itertools import permutations
S,k = input().split()
[print(x) for x in sorted(map("".join,permutations(S,int(k))))]
```

Current Output for input : hs 2

hs

sh

[None, None]

Expected Output for input : hs 2

hs

sh

Comment: This is why it is recommended *not* to use list comprehensions for *side effects*. Things where you don't actually need the list, but want the code to perform some action such as `print`.

Comment: `print(..)` returns `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(..)` is a function that writes to the standard output channel, and *returns* `None`. So you are here adding `None`s to your list.

You can create a list of values with:

```
sorted(map("".join,permutations(S,int(k)))
```

although for a large `k`, this will eventually go out of memory. You can simply sort the `S` in advance, which is more efficient and you can use `permutations` here in an iterable-fasion way, and thus reduce the amount of memory, like:

```
for p in permutations(sorted(S),int(k)):
    print(''.join(p))
```

As a result the algorithm will take *O(n log n + n<sup>k</sup>)*, instead of *O(n<sup>k</sup>×k×log n)*. The memory footprint will be *O(n)* instead of *O(n<sup>k</sup>)* with *n* the number of characters in the string, and *k* the number of items in the permutation.

Comment: can I do this same using List comprehension

Comment: @San: well the `[None, None]` is not printed if you run the program. The shell will simply print it. But using list comprehension would be a horrible idea, since that would again generate a list of *O(n^k)* `None` items, blowing up memory. It is of couse a pity that list comprehension is not syntactical sugar for monads, like some functional programming languages :)